# openldap - cannot create ldif file from schema file

Tags: ldap, schema, openldap, ldif

I'm trying to add my own schema to OpenLDAP, but when I convert .schema -> .ldif using slaptest, there's nothing in the destination directory except for some default schemas. Mine is not being created. I added the path to slapd.conf. I'm creating the .schema file via Apache Directory Studio:

```
attributetype ( 2.0.0.0.1 
    NAME 'objectName'
    DESC ''
    EQUALITY caseIgnoreMatch
    SUBSTR caseIgnoreSubstringsMatch
    SYNTAX 1.3.6.1.4.1.1466.115.121.1.15 )
attributetype ( 2.0.0.0.2 
    NAME 'editableObject'
    DESC ''
    EQUALITY caseIgnoreMatch
    SUBSTR caseIgnoreSubstringsMatch
    SYNTAX 1.3.6.1.4.1.1466.115.121.1.15
    USAGE userApplications )
attributetype ( 2.0.0.0.3 
    NAME 'mailDesc'
    DESC ''
    EQUALITY caseIgnoreMatch
    SUBSTR caseIgnoreSubstringsMatch
    SYNTAX 1.3.6.1.4.1.1466.115.121.1.15
    USAGE userApplications )
attributetype ( 2.0.0.0.4 
    NAME 'visibleObject'
    DESC ''
    EQUALITY caseIgnoreMatch
    SUBSTR caseIgnoreSubstringsMatch
    SYNTAX 1.3.6.1.4.1.1466.115.121.1.15
    USAGE userApplications )
attributetype ( 2.0.0.0.5 
    NAME 'objectDesc'
    DESC ''
    EQUALITY caseIgnoreMatch
    SUBSTR caseIgnoreSubstringsMatch
    SYNTAX 1.3.6.1.4.1.1466.115.121.1.15
    USAGE userApplications )
objectclass ( 2.0.0.1.1 
    NAME 'myObject'
    DESC ''
    SUP top
    AUXILIARY
    MAY ( objectName $ objectDesc ) )
objectclass ( 2.0.0.1.2 
    NAME 'myRole'
    DESC ''
    AUXILIARY
    MAY ( editableObject $ visibleObject ) )
objectclass ( 2.0.0.1.3 
    NAME 'myUser'
    DESC ''
    AUXILIARY
    MAY ( editableObject $ visibleObject $ mailDesc ) )
```

Do you have any ideas why there is no .ldif file?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> I'm trying to add my own schema to OpenLDAP, but when I convert
>   .schema -> .ldif using slaptest, there's nothing in the destination
>   directory except for some default schemas.

`slaptest` did exactly what you described : convert schema to ldif. You never added the ldif to the directory. (In any way `slaptest` can add the ldif to the directory, as hinted by the command name, it is to make tests, not to modify the directory)

> Mine is not being created.

The LDIF has been created, it is just not added to the directory

> I added the path to slapd.conf

There is no `slapd.conf` to use for OpenLDAP configuration since years. You have to use the `cn=config` branch to do so

> I'm creating the .schema file via Apache Directory Studio

As stated above, `.schema` files were used by the old OpenLDAP configuration system. Now you have to use the `cn=config` branch

For more informations :

- The schemas are stored inside the `cn=config` branch at : `cn=schema,cn=config`
- To add you schema you have to add an entry like : 
  `cn={x}myschema,cn=schema,cn=config` which contains an ldif like for example :

```
    dn: cn={4}myschema,cn=schema,cn=config
    objectClass: olcSchemaConfig
    cn: {4}myschema
    olcAttributeTypes: {0}( 0.0.0.0.0.1.1 NAME 'code' DESC 'Some code identificati
     on' SUP description )
    olcAttributeTypes: {1}( 0.0.0.0.0.1.2 NAME ( 'latitude' 'lat' ) DESC 'Latitude
     ' SUP description )
    olcObjectClasses: {5}( 0.0.0.0.0.2.6 NAME 'groupCustom' DESC 'A group of nam
     es (DNs) with optionnal member attribute' SUP top STRUCTURAL MUST ( cn ) MAY 
     ( member $ seeAlso $ owner $ description ) )
    olcObjectClasses: {6}( 0.0.0.0.0.2.7 NAME 'groupDynamic' DESC 'A DYNAMIC g
     roup of names (DNs) with optionnal member attribute' SUP top STRUCTURAL MUST 
     ( cn $ dynListURL ) MAY ( member $ seeAlso $ owner $ description  ) )
```

Note : This example is the result of a `slapcat` and in no way the LDIF describing the `ldapadd` operation to perform to add the schema to the directory. But you still can import it with Apache Directory Studio if you do not want to write the LDIF to use with the `ldapadd` operation

For more information, consider reading http://www.zytrax.com/books/ldap/ch6/slapd-config.html#use-schemas